# Convert 910 to an 8 bit, two’s complement number

Tags: digital-logic

Convert 910 to an 8 bit, two’s complement number.

0000 1001

1111 0111

0100 1000

0001 0010

I convert 910 to binary (910)_10 = (0000001110001110)_2

but when I reverse  10001110 to 01110001 in order to give me 2'scomplement , it's clear that isn't in the choice answer

I need help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) standard says it is "implementation defined". I'd say this is a typo and it should have been $9_{10}$. In that case the first answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your question makes no sense since 910 can't be expressed by a 8 bit 2s complement number.  Such a number can only take on values from -128 to +127.

Answer (score 0):

To get the two's complement, just get the binary number and then toggle from right to left all bits starting from the **FIRST** one.
I.e.

910_2    = 0000 0011 1000 1110

910_2_TC = 1111 1100 0111 00 **1** 0

Start from the **1** marked in bold and move left.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A two's complement is the same as one's complement (invert all bits), then increment by 1.  Your explanation makes little sense, but simply toggling bits sounds like a one's complement.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, My Digital Logic book had this exact definition when it was explaining two's compliment methods. You start at the very right of the binary stream and leave every bit as it is until you encounter the first "1". Leave this "1" and then invert all remaining bits in the stream as you continue along from right to left. It sounds non-intuitive in words but it's a much simpler, single step methodology to get the two's compliment. Otherwise you have to first invert all the bits and then add one, thus an additional step. It works out the same but combines steps.

Comment: That explanation makes sense, but not what you wrote above.  Or at least what you wrote above is ambiguous.  "First one" is a really bad choice of words, which is how I misinterpreted what you are trying to say.

Comment: I tried to be as short as I could but now I realize that it was somehow ambiguous. Thanks @sherrellbc for the longer explanation.